# Install popcorn maker developer on windows

Tags: node.js, git, npm, popcornjs

I'm a pure nooby in this but I would really need to install popcorn maker developer to be able to modify it a bit and use it on a website as a webapp.

Here is the git hub link to it: [popcorn webmaker](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn.webmaker.org)

I tried to follow their guide but it does not seem to work I install node, and think I install make-valet, I think it worked but I'm not sure. But when I try to $npm install I get this error:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN engine sqlite3@2.1.17: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6.13 < 0.11.0"}       (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN deprecated extend@1.1.3: Please update to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated tap-consumer@0.0.1: this is merged into the 'tap' module now
npm WARN deprecated tap-results@0.0.2: this is merged into the 'tap' module now

> dtrace-provider@0.2.8 install C:\cygwin64\home\Me   \popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\messina\node_modules\bunyan\node_modules\dtra    ce-provider
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\messina\node_modules\bunyan\node_modules\dtrace-provider>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-    gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the  PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\messina\node_modules\bunyan\node_modules\dtrace-provider
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing dtrace-provider@0.2.8

> sqlite3@2.1.17 install C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\sqlite3
> node build.js

[sqlite3]: Checking for http://node- sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.1.a-node-v14-win32-ia32.tar.gz
[sqlite3]: http://node-sqlite3.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/node_sqlite3-v2.1.a-node-v14-win32-ia32.tar.gz not found, falling back to source compile (Error: Server returned 404)

C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\sqlite3>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Build failed
[sqlite3]: 1

> node-expat@2.0.0 install C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\webmaker-download-locales\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\cygwin64\home\Mee\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\webmaker-download-locales\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\node_modules\webmaker-download-locales\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing sqlite3@2.1.17
npm WARN deprecated lingo@0.0.5: This project is abandoned
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\cygwin64\home\Me\popcorn.webmaker.org\npm-debug.log
```

I really don't understand where the error is coming from. I installed node using the .exe file and when I $ node -v I get the 0.12.1 so it has worked but I'm not sure how to check the rest. 
This would help me so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm WARN engine sqlite3@2.1.17: wanted: {"node":">= 0.6.13 < 0.11.0"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})`

`gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the  PYTHON env variable.`

It isn't clear? :P